# jquery horizontal scroll event - Edit

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

Hi there I have a horizontally scrolling gallery that i want to add dynamic captions to, the captions are static on the page and I would like them to toggle on and off when the user scrolls past each image.

heres a mock up of the page:

http://www.jonathantopf.com/imijstudio/

For a proof of concept i have a little red square in the above gallery that i would like to use to trigger an event when it enters the screen. Any ideas?

I had a go using waypoints but couldn't figure out how to set it to listen for horizontal scroll events. I'm very new to jquery as you might be able to tell so any help is greatly appreciated,

Heres what I tried so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#blob").waypoint(function() {
    alert('waypoint reached.');
});


});
```

and here's the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function ( selector, context ) {
    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );
} has no method 'isWindow'
```

UPDATE: upgraded to latest version of jquery, that seemed to fix the consloe error. It works now but only when the square enters the frame vertically, i can t find how to set the orientation to horizontal.

Thanks

jon

Comment: just modified the post so far with my attempts, im very new so I'm still trying to get to grips with how jquery works, j

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey you just need to use the $(window).scroll and the value from scrollleft ive done a simple test for you here:

http://jsfiddle.net/vJUXy/

let me know if ive misunderstood?
Alex

Comment: thats amazing! and no plugins, genius!

Comment: you're welcome, just added a little thing to also illustrate how to change the text as you scroll also so you can see how easy it is to implement http://jsfiddle.net/vJUXy/1/

Answer (score 2):

Update your JQuery. `isWindow` was added in 1.4.3 (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isWindow/) and you're using 1.4.2.

Comment: Thanks mat, just updated jquery and it fixes the error, but it now fires when i scroll vertically, I need it to work horizontally, I couldnt find any reference in waypoint to specify the scroll orientation

Comment: https://github.com/imakewebthings/jquery-waypoints/issues/14 You have to implement your own function =/