# Loading new content when user reaches right side of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scroll

There is plenty of plugins that allow to load content when the user reaches the bottom of the page, however I can't find jquery plugin that would allow you to load content when user reaches the right side of the document.

Is there a good strategy to do this ?

Is there a good plugin that does this ?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Try to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105152/jquery-horizontal-scroll-event-edit and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186622/is-there-a-vertical-scroll-event-in-jquery posts.

Comment: I don't know if the question should be closed as duplication, or kept open as this could have a better search term :)

Comment: @mr.The yes, I have seen these links, however this basically means creating a plugin from scratch, while I was interested if there a good plugin to do so...

Comment: @Val what might be the better search term in your opinion ?

Comment: @peter I mean't more people are more likely to search for the solution as you have on the title, therefore this would be a great question to land on for people with similar issue... To answer you question, yes, the plugin is very simple to be created, or simply use, the onscroll event to detect when it reaches the end by choosing `.scrollWidth` to detect total srollable width, then `scrollLeft()` how far they have scrolled so far,

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div').scroll(function (){
  var padder = 50;
  if( $(this).scrollLeft() >= $(this).scrollWidth -padder){
     //load more content as the user has scrolled 50px less than, the end, 
  }
})
```

I think something like this would do it ....

Comment: btw, should you need to use it for future elements change first line to `$('div').live('scroll',function (){`

Comment: also, you may want to use `parseInt()` if the unit `px` is returned with `scrollWidth` :)

Comment: Great, this make sense, the next step probably is to write actual plugin and publish it on github))

Comment: Hmm, dear @Val Shouldn't I be listening to the window events rather then div events ?

Answer (score 0):

This does the job nicely:

```
//Scroll
  var padder = 150;
  $(document).live('scroll',function (){
     if($(this).scrollLeft() > padder){
    $.post("data.txt", { bla: "1", blu: "ax" },
        function(data) {
         //TODO add a check when reach the end
         padder = padder +200;
         $("#events_list").width($("#events_list").width()+200);
         $("#events_list").append(data);
        },"text");
     }
  });
```